# How to make the People search query matching less restrictive and 'smarter'?

Tags: people-search, sorting, ranking, query-rule

Our client has a People directory set up on SP2013 on premises. We are getting complaints that employees who try to find colleagues by searching on their name (usually the first name) don’t get any results when they make a type/spelling error, even if it’s only one letter wrong. Then SP comes back with a message like “couldn’t find any results”.

So the problem seems to be that it’s being too restrictive. How can we (using OOTB configuration)  “loose up” the query matching or configure that it instead shows suggestions or related/similar names, or things like “did you mean…” (I think it actually can do that OOTB (checkbox in Settings right?) but very limited in my experience).

FYI:  our current settings are a result source with type: Search Results for People.

Any advice on how to configure the result source, query, sorting, ranking model to achieve a better and smarter search experience for the end users?

Answer (score 0):

OOTB The Search Summary Web Part provides a maybe useful function. Try searching SharePoint for "Microsfot" and you'll get  "Did you mean Microsoft?" as result.